# Proof that $P(\cup_{n=1}^\infty\cap_{m=n}^{\infty}A_m^c)=1$

Tags: probability-theory

Let $A_1,A_2,...$ be events and P be probability measure. If $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_n)<\infty$ then prove that

$P(\cup_{n=1}^\infty\cap_{m=n}^{\infty}A_m^c)=1$

ie. $\cup_{n=1}^\infty\cap_{m=n}^{\infty}A_m^c$ is the entire sample space.

any idea how to do this? how should I apply the fact $\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty}P(A_n)<\infty$ to prove it?

Thanks for your help

Comment: That $P(A)=1$ does not imply that $A$ is the entire sample space. As for the question, try showing that the complement has probability zero.

Comment: `\Sigma` $\to$ `\sum`.

Answer (score 2):

First note that $P(\def\sls{\bigcup_{n \ge 1}\bigcap_{m\ge n} A_m^c}\sls) = 1$ does not imply that $\sls$ is the whole of $\Omega$, it just says, that its complement, $\def\sli{\bigcap_{n\ge 1} \bigcup_{m\ge n} A_m}\sli$ has measure zero. But now to your question, note first that 
$$ \bigcup_{m\ge 1} A_m \supseteq \bigcup_{m\ge 2} A_m \supseteq \cdots $$
hence by continuity of measure 
$$ P\left(\sli\right) = \lim_{n \to \infty} P\left(\bigcup_{m\ge n} A_m\right) $$
Now use subadditivity and $\sum_n P(A_n) < \infty$ to conclude.

Comment: Did you mistype the relation $...\cap_{m\geq 2}A_m\subset \cap_{m\geq 1}A_m$(Shouldn't it be $\cup_{m\geq 2}A_m$?)

Comment: Yes, thanks, corrected.